# Find linked "child/parents" in pythons dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem I hope you can help me with. I have the following dictionary:

```
    {
    '100': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2},
    '101': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2,'children': ['105', '102']},
    '102': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2,'children': ['103']},
    '103': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2},
    '104': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2,'children': ['105', '102']},
    '105': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2,'children': ['124']},
    '106': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2},
    '107': {'name': Glenn,'age': 25,'cars': 2,'children': ['199']},
    }
```

The task is: for every entry in this list, figure out if they have a parent in this list, and if so, make an entry in their dict with `parent: ['101','104']` etc.

As you see, some of the persons do not have a parent in this list, and should therefore not get this "parent" entry added. And other people have children who are not on the list, and those children are ignored as we have no info about them.

I have tried the following:

```
     def addParentInfo(patients):
        for pkey, pvalue in patients.items():
            for pkey2,pvalue2 in patients.items():
                if pkey in pvalue["children"]:
                    pvalue[parent] = [pkey2]
```

But it seems so unorganized, and I don't know how to take care of the "children outside the list" problem, and when a person has two parents in the list, I should add them to the list instead of resetting pvalue[parent].

So can someone teach me how to make this effective and smooth? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import pprint            

for k, v in data.items(): #data is the main dictionary
    if 'children' in v:
        for child in v['children']:
            if child in data:
                data[child].setdefault('parent', []).append(k)

pprint.pprint(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'100': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'name': 'Glenn'},
 '101': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'children': ['105', '102'], 'name': 'Glenn'},
 '102': {'age': 25,
         'cars': 2,
         'children': ['103'],
         'name': 'Glenn',
         'parent': ['101', '104']},
 '103': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'name': 'Glenn', 'parent': ['102']},
 '104': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'children': ['105', '102'], 'name': 'Glenn'},
 '105': {'age': 25,
         'cars': 2,
         'children': ['124'],
         'name': 'Glenn',
         'parent': ['101', '104']},
 '106': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'name': 'Glenn'},
 '107': {'age': 25, 'cars': 2, 'children': ['199'], 'name': 'Glenn'}}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this so the parent info is in a list, and not in a set? :)

Comment: @Nick Yes, just use: `setdefault('parent', []).appendd(k)`

Comment: Thanks, that just the solution i was looking for. Thanks for your time and helpfullness :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def addParentInfo(patients):
    for k, v in patients.items():
        for ck in v.get('children', []):
            if ck in patients:
                patients[ck].setdefault('parent', []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `d` is your original dictionary, this dict comprehension should do the trick:

```
d = {k: {k: v for k, v in v.items() if v}
    for k, v in d.items() if v.__setitem__('parents',
    [p for p, v in d.items() if 'children' in v and k in v['children']]) or True}
```